# How can I allow moving and copying by dragging rows in an NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nsdragginginfo

I have an `NSTableView` which I wish to be able to drag and drop rows to move them, and drag and drop while holding Option (as per [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragsource.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000976-CJBFBADF)) to copy them.

I have the following code in my view controller, which is also the `dataSource` of the table view.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self.tableView registerForDraggedTypes:@[kRowIndexesPasteboardType]];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:rowIndexes];
    [pasteboard declareTypes:@[kRowIndexesPasteboardType] owner:self];
    [pasteboard setData:data forType:kRowIndexesPasteboardType];
    return YES;
}

- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation {
    // Only allow dropping above/below.
    return dropOperation == NSTableViewDropAbove ? (NSDragOperationMove|NSDragOperationCopy) : NSDragOperationNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info row:(NSInteger)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation {
    if (dropOperation == NSTableViewDropAbove) {
        NSPasteboard* pasteboard = [info draggingPasteboard];
        NSData* rowData = [pasteboard dataForType:kRowIndexesPasteboardType];
        NSIndexSet* rowIndexes = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:rowData];

        BOOL copy = ???;
        if (copy) {
            // Copy items at rowIndexes to row.
        } else {
            // Move items at rowIndexes to row.
        }
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

1. How can I make the default dragging operation be moving, and only be copying when the Option key is held down? Currently it defaults to copy straight away.
2. In `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:` how can I tell whether the operation was a copy operation or a drop operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [this discussion](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/150107-nstableview-and-dragging-cursor.html) the value of `draggingSourceOperationMask` will be `NSDragOperationEvery` (unless changed) when no modifier keys are held:

> When it comes back
>   to your table as a drop validation without any modification by the
>   user (no option key down) then any of the original options need to be
>   considered as being possible. Your validation should then pick the
>   operation (out of the source allowed options) that you will do based
>   on what makes sense for the target of the drop.

Which means that the following method will return `NSDragOperationCopy` when the Option key is held down, and `NSDragOperationMove` otherwise:

```
- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation {
    // Allow moving or copying the rows.
    NSDragOperation moveOrCopy = (info.draggingSourceOperationMask == NSDragOperationCopy ? NSDragOperationCopy : NSDragOperationMove);
    // Only allow dropping above/below.
    return dropOperation == NSTableViewDropAbove ? moveOrCopy : NSDragOperationNone;
}
```

Likewise, the operation can be checked in the `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:` in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In validateDrop: return [info draggingSourceOperationMask] & (NSDragOperationMove | NSDragOperationCopy) or NSDragOperationNone.

In acceptDrop: check [info draggingSourceOperationMask] & NSDragOperationMove.

Comment: The `draggingSourceOperationMask` is -1 when just dragging the item which means that `NSDragOperationCopy & NSDragOperationMove` is returned, when I just want `NSDragOperationMove`.